# sqoop, select specific columns

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

In the sqoop statements, is there a provision where we can select only specific columns from oracle side?

## 1 : works

```
sqoop import --target-dir /tmp/customers --query "SELECT * FROM schema1.customers where item>=1234 and \$CONDITIONS" --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.companyxyz.com:4567/prod --username xyz --password xyz --hive-drop-import-delims -m 8 --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --split-by cust_id
```

## 2 : fails

```
sqoop import --target-dir /tmp/customers --query "SELECT cust_id, name, address, date, history, occupation FROM schema1.customers where item>=1234 and \$CONDITIONS" --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.companyxyz.com:4567/prod --username xyz --password xyz --hive-drop-import-delims -m 8 --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \\ --split-by cust_id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use --columns --table --where clauses to achieve it. Sample is below:

```
sqoop import  
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.companyxyz.com:4567/prod/DATABASE=schema1
--username xyz 
--password xyz 
--table customers
--columns cust_id, name, address, date, history, occupation  
--where item>=1234 
--target-dir /tmp//customers
--m 8
--split-by cust_id
--fields-terminated-by , 
--escaped-by \ 
--hive-drop-import-delims  
--map-column-java
  cust_id=string, name=string, address=string, date=string, history=string, occupation=string
```

Comment: for the --columns I put "cust_id, name, ...etc" and same for the --where and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `SELECT cust_id, name, address, date, history, occupation FROM schema1.customers where item>=1234` is incorrect. I tried all possible scenarios. Try running it in your database. Also have you dropped directory /tmp/customers before running your second statement. You should paste the errors as well.

```
sqoop import \
     --connect "jdbc:mysql://sandbox.hortonworks.com:3306/retail_db" \
     --username=retail_dba \
     --password=hadoop \
     --query "select department_id, department_name from departments where \$CONDITIONS" \
     --target-dir /user/root//testing \
     --split-by department_id \
     --outdir java_files \
     --hive-drop-import-delims \
     -m 8 \
     --fields-terminated-by , \
     --escaped-by '\'
```